# How to set an entity value to another value than the one in database in jpa

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

In my MySQL database I have a table X with a field 'foo' which can be null. I'm using jpa to present all functionality of this database to my front-end. What I want is that whenever an entity of table X is requested and the value of 'foo' is null, this value is automatically changed to another value. This value, however, should not be persisted, it should only be seen by my front-end. In my database 'foo' should stay null. How can this be done? Can I just implement this in the setter of field 'foo'? Or is this setter not used by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement @PrePersist or @PostUpdate to add some functionality just before updating the object into db or you can use hibernate events do do the same thing in the other time. Hibernate will use setters when you put your annotations on the setter instead of local variables.

> Depending on whether you annotate fields or methods, the access type
>   used by Hibernate will be field or property...
>   [source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity)

Answer (score 0):

In Entity X has the setDefault getDefaultFoo and methods. To be called by the Front-End, the getDefaultFoo returns the default value if the attribute is null. setDefaultFoo and sets the value of foo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class X implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "foo")
    private String foo;

    public String getDefaultFoo() {
        return foo != null ? foo : "0";
    }

    public void setDefaultFoo(String foo) {
        setFoo(foo);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```